# Add Check Box to each product and use the selected Check boxes values on another page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

The product list will be populated from MySql Database using PHP code and is having a check box for each product.

On that page, whenever a check box is clicked, I need that product to be highlighted and store its value to some other array type variable to pass that value to another page.

Code for product list creation:

```
<?php
$cnt=0;
$rslt = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT Icode,Name,Size,Style FROM productinfo");

if(!$rslt){
    die(mysqli_error($conn));
}else{
    echo "<table width='100%'>";
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rslt)){
        if($cnt==0){
            echo "<tr>";
        }
        echo "<td width='30%'>
          <div class='card'>
            <img src='upload/"."download.jpg"."' alt='Avatar' style='width:100px' >
            <div class='container'>
              <h4><b>".$row['Name']."&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type='checkbox' name=".$row['Icode']." value=".$row['Icode']." onclick=' echo return OptionsSelected(this)'/> </b></h4> 
              <p>".$row['Size']."</p> 
              <p>".$row['Icode']."</p> 
            </div>";
            ?>

    <!--  <button role="button" data-toggle="modal" data-id="<?php print $row['Icode']?>" onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='block'" style="width:auto;">Inquiry</button>
          </div>
    <?php
    echo "</td>";
    if($cnt==2){
      $cnt=0;
      echo "</tr>";
    }
    else
      $cnt = $cnt + 1;
  }
}
echo "</table>";
?>
```

Comment: You can simplify the code here by taking out unnecessary PHP interpretation and posting plain HTML. :)

Comment: But what about when required to get item codes when a check box is clicked and save it in some variable to pass it to some other page. Could u please provide an example for this